# Bind a section in my Appsettings Section to Dictionary<int,int>

Tags: c#, .net-5

I have the following section in the app settings:

```
 "ProductSettings": {
 "ProductValues": {      
  1: 14,
  2: 30
}
```

my main objective is to bind to my object below:

```
public class ProductSettings
{
     public Dictionary<int, int> ProductValues{ get; set; }         
}
```

as simply as possible.

i.e. somthing like this :

```
services.Configure<ProductSettings>(configuration.GetSection("ProductSettings"));
```

I am willing to change my appsettings but I need a Dictionary<int, int> and to be configured like above i.e. `services.Configure`. it works when 1 and 2 as strings, but I need a dictionary of ints.

Comment: Do you need really need the index in your values? Can't you have an array, like: `"ProductValues": [14,30]`?

Comment: That is not a valid json to my knowledge.

Comment: @GuruStron I agree it isn't valid json but I need a dictionary of int and int in the end. If {"key":1,{"value":14} worked I would do that.

Comment: @PeterCsala it's not an index it's the ID

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    ProductSettings productSettings = new ProductSettings
    {
        ProductValues = configuraton
        .GetSection("ProductSettings:ProductValues")
        .Get<Dictionary<string, string>>()
        .ToDictionary(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Key), i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Value))
    };
```

output

```
{
  ProductValues: {
    1: 14,
    2: 30
  }
}
```

and you have to fix the bug. your json is not valid. Appsetings is a dictionary <string,object>. You can't have a number as a key

```
"ProductSettings": {
 "ProductValues": {      
  "1": 14,
  "2": 30
}
}
```

you can configure only appsettings section. So if you need dictionary<int, int> you will have to create a special  product settings service

startup

```
services.Configure<ConfigProductSettings>(configuration
                    .GetSection("ProductSettings"));

services.AddScoped<ProductSettingsService>();
```

code

```
public class ProductSettingsService
{
    private readonly ProductSettings _productSettings;


    public ProductSettingsService(IOptions<ConfigProductSettings> settings)
    {
        _productSettings = new ProductSettings
        {
        ProductValues = settings.Value.ProductValues
        .ToDictionary(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Key), i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Value))
        };
    }
    public ProductSettings GetSettings()
    {
        return _productSettings;
    }
    public int GetProductValue(int i)
    {
        return _productSettings.ProductValues[i];
    }
}
```

classes

```
public class ProductSettings
{
    public Dictionary<int, int> ProductValues { get; set; }
}
public class ConfigProductSettings
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> ProductValues { get; set; }
}
```